# Accessing an attribute on a child that's set with a data binding

Tags: polymer

I have a little bit of markup that looks like this:

```
<polymer-element name="blog-post" noscript>
  <template>

    <mark-down>
      <textarea value="{{post}}"></textarea>
    </mark-down>

    <polymer-localstorage name="my-blog-editor" value="{{post}}">
    </polymer-localstorage>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

I'd like the mark-down tag to be able to see the value of the textarea but I'm having a hard time knowing when to query for it.

Inside of mark-down my code looks something like this:

```
  attached: function() {
      this.textarea = this.$.textareaContent.getDistributedNodes()[0];  // this grabs the textarea element

      // create an observer instance
      var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
          console.log(mutation);
        });
      });

      // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
      observer.observe(this.textarea, { attributes: true });
  }
```

Unfortunately the mutation observer never fires. I've tried checking for the value of textarea directly in attached and domReady but it's always null. The only success I've had is to use a setTimeout to check for the value asynchronously.

Comment: Is this `textarea` necessary? The shortest path to making this work involves simply removing it. It's not clear to me what it's doing there. Also, why not use https://github.com/PolymerLabs/marked-element?

Comment: I was just playing around with the idea of an element that changes behavior depending on the children it's provided. In this case my mark-down element will normally render any markdown it's provided but if someone puts a textarea inside of it then it becomes an editor that  can toggle between showing the textarea and showing the rendered markdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textarea` is specifically difficult to use in this manner, because you cannot observe it's content changing with MutationObservers, only with events.

Worse still, there is no signal at all for setting `textarea.value` (which is what your binding will do).

If you want to use `textarea` like this, suggest you expose a property on the `mark-down` element for binding a value, and listen to events from the `textarea` to monitor user edits.

```
<mark-down value="{{post}}">
  <textarea></textarea>
</mark-down>
```